# How do I know if I am shadow banned?

Tags: support, banning

If I don't get an answer to this question, then I know that I am now shadow banned.

Comment: Why do you think shadow banning is a thing on SO?

Comment: Because of how shadow banning works. You wouldn't even know you'd been shadow banned. Thank you for responding, I'm just coming off a string of ignored questions.

Comment: I know what shadow banning is, but I don't know why you think SO employs it. They're quite clear when they ban someone generally. And, I'm sorry to say, your questions look like bad questions, rather than simply ignored. One of them seems to be three questions. One of them is a request for an off-site resource. The third one I can see has comments on it.

Comment: What point would there be to implement shadow banning, from SO's perspective?

Comment: You posted this question and people downvoted and commented to you. You're clearly not wandering stack exchange on an alternate plane of existence reserved for the damned bits of the internet.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: To be fair, he only has 3 questions, the last of which posted about 30 minutes ago, the ones before that were ~20 days ago (no answers, comments, votes) and then ~a year (with comments). I can imagine why the OP thought it was a possibility.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've wondered this once upon a time myself, was just pointing out the obvious answer. :)

Comment: That's because my questions get auto deleted by bots. Look at how old my account it.

Comment: Hello meta people; this is a completely valid question - the fact that SE doesn't use this technique doesn't preclude people from thinking kit might. If you think the question is insufficiently researched find the dupe and vote to close,

Comment: I'd answer but I can't read your question, as you're shadowbanned.

Comment: Is this something worth adding to the Help Center?

Answer (score 11):

Shadowbanning (or hellbanning) does not happen on Stack Exchange.

Quoting [waffles' answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93857/229438):

> Hellbanning, slowbanning, errorbanning, and randombanning are all things we have never experimented with and do not intend to.

Comment: Related http://blog.codinghorror.com/suspension-ban-or-hellban/

Comment: FWIW [meta-tag:triage] limits question visibility, but technically, this isn't ban, because people review it, and it's available by direct link (a more appropriate term would likely be pre-moderation)